# Why is my load->view giving me an undefined property in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I haven't used CodeIgniter in over a year. I remember it was useful for quick, simple projects but I seem to have fallen at the first hurdle here. I can't seem to load my default view. Here is the controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

  private $data = array();

  public function __constructor() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

  public function home() {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('nav');
        $this->load->view('home');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

This gives me:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Home::$load
>
> Filename: controllers/home.php
>
> Line Number: 13

But I can't figure out why.

In my config I have set 'html', 'url' and 'form' to autoload. And my routes defaults correctly to 'home'. It's kinda frustrating because I know it's something really simple that I'm forgetting here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your method has same name with the view you are calling which is home

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple. I just forgot that was a constraint.

Comment: Method name could be same with view name.

Comment: try to answer the problem with another solution if that's the case

Answer (score 3):

Your `__constructor` is wrong. Use `__construct` instead of `__constructor`

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(); 
}
```